# How can I change the FormHelper's input template for text input?

Tags: cakephp-3.7

I’m trying to change the template for `<input type=text/>` elements. But when I do it loses the value when in edit context.
I change the FormHelper template from

```
'templates' => [
    'input' => '<input type="{{type}}" name="{{name}}"{{attrs}}/>',
]
```

to

```
'templates' => [
    'input' => '<my-input type="{{type}}" name="{{name}}"{{attrs}}></my-input>',
]
```

but it doesn’t get the ‘value’ attribute then and the input field appears blank.

There must be a way of ensuring that the value get's passed in – ideally via attributes of the element as the `value` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You earlier implementation should work, 
Do make sure that you set the name of the input field similar to the variable name in the database for it to pick the value automatically.

Otherwise you can always set the value attribute of the FormHelper to set it manually.